# Blank PHP/Index Page on Android HTTP Post Request

Tags: php, android, http, post, authentication

Upon using the code samples below, I try to send a HTTP request to validate a username and password entry to a PHP script (returning either 1 or 0 in an echo).

Using HTTP Assistant, testing the HTTP Post request has the expected results... But for some reason, when logging the 'res' String (the HTTP response) in the java code, I get a blank PHP/Index page:

```
<!DOCTYPEHTMLPUBLIC"-//W3C//DTDHTML3.2Final//EN"><html><title>Indexof/</title></head><body><h1>Indexof/</h1><ul><li><ahref="cgi-bin/">cgi-bin/</a></li></ul></body></html>
```

Code: [HomeActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/ydPmQRad) and [Http.java](http://pastebin.com/rAhb92CM)

Have I done something wrong code-wise? Or is this a server issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing there is the standard webserver listing of a directory. So you probably have the wrong URL you're hitting. Is there any redirect magic involved?

[edit] As you have controll of the PHP page yourself, do the following: Edit it so that it accepts parameters per GET and try to call the page via your android browser with the username and password as GET parameters . If that works, you've at least a clue that it's possible from your phone.

Comment: The URL is fine, I tried using HTTPAssistant (an Adobe AIR script) to send a form generated HTTP request which also worked fine/outputted the expected result. I can also enter a URL that doesn't exist (e.g. use.php instead of user.php) which still has the samme outcome.

Comment: well, what does your skript do if you pass it wrong parameters?

Comment: if($database->checkLogin($username,$password)) echo 1;
 else echo 0;
checkLogin is a function that was included from another PHP file that does the query.

Comment: @Tommy, You say if you use the wrong page you get the same outcome, so it means you are using the wrong page address most probably.  Can you run [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to sniff/checkout/watch the traffic in its entirety to see what's happening?

Comment: @David I installed it and had a go... But it's all jargon to me, I have no recollection of what is going on. But I can clarify that sending requests to other websites than my own/host's returns non-blank HTML-like responses. Which must be a sign that my web host is blocking some form of request from my Android emulator? I can't round up the problem to address them though...

Comment: @TommyPlummer, I understand, Wireshark isn't the most intuitive app around.  Let's see... try this: See if you can get to see all the HTTP Headers sent and received in your requests.  If you can get that right then you are a good way along to solving your problem.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check this

Comment: @David Thanks for the advice, I'll have a look when I get back from lectures.

Comment: @LordT I've attempted a very simple php page of <? echo "hello"; ?>, sent a GET request with no parameters, and it still returns the same blank index HTML. Though I'll try to specifically repeat your instructions when I get home and post on here.

Comment: well, have you tried opening that simple page via your browser? does it work (on the phone?)

Comment: I AM A FOOL... There was mobile redirecting which I -completely- forgot about, and didn't realise it would apply for this... The .htaccess that had this information was passed to the directory that the Android application was communicating with. So @LordT, your comment about the redirecting was correct.

Oh dear, I should just hang up the boots and retire early eh?!

Thanks for all your time.